# I need to replace environment.Newline with a <br/> html tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, textarea

I am building an ecommerce site.  When the user copy pasta's a list into a "description" text area I need to be able to display it that way inside a `<p>` tag.  Right now it is all jumbled together.  I have tried the replace method to replace the newline with a `<br/>`, but it displays the `<br/>` as if its part of the string.  I'm sure it's not hard, I'm just having a hard time finding my answer.

Here is the code in my view:

`<p id="description"><%: Model.Description.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>") %></p>`

In my controller I just save the encoded string in my database and then grab it out and pass it as is to the view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a regular expression. If you are doing this with javascript you can try this

```
value = value.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

That means, find all instances of the new line character in the string and replace it with a html line break.

Answer (score 0):

The `<br/>` is shown as text because the contents of your control get html encoded automatically.

Use an `Literal` control to display the list, the html-tags will then not be encoded and `<br/>` will be shown as a line break.

Keep in mind though, that showing unencoded data coming from a user can be dangerous. (scripting attacks)